# How to resolve dependencies problems on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, dependencies

when I run "npm install", the console tells me this errors:

```
elena@elena-dev:~/PROYECTO FINAL CTD/grupo-12/frontend/proyecto-integrador$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-grid-gallery@0.5.6
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, react-select)
npm ERR!   20 more (@emotion/styled, @mui/base, @mui/icons-material, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0 || ^16.0" from react-grid-gallery@0.5.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-grid-gallery
npm ERR!   react-grid-gallery@"^0.5.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0 || ^16.0" from react-grid-gallery@0.5.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-grid-gallery
npm ERR!     react-grid-gallery@"^0.5.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/elena/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/elena/.npm/_logs/2022-09-03T20_19_47_945Z-debug-0.log
```

With "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" is fine, but this may not be a definitive solution.

Please help.

Comment: This `react-grid-gallery` library is obsolete and uses a very old version of react. Better use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the peer dependencies of `react-grid-gallery@0.5.6` package:

```
$ npm view react-grid-gallery@0.5.6 peerDependencies
{ react: '^15.0 || ^16.0' }
```

As you can see, it uses `react` package as its peer dependency with version: `^15.0` or `^16.0`. But in your project, the `react` package's version is `^18.2.0`, which is incompatible. The warning will display when using npm v7.

Two safe solutions:

- Downgrade the `react` package to those two compatible versions. E.g.

```
$ npm i react@^16.0 react-dom@^16.0 -S
```

- Upgrade the `react-grid-gallery` package to the latest version(1.0.0 until 2023.7.3) which supports the new version of React. Let's check the peer dependencies of the latest version:

```
$ npm view react-grid-gallery@1.0.0 peerDependencies
{ react: '>=16.14.0' }
```

It is compatible with `react` with version `>=16.14.0`. `React 18.x` is ok.

Note: Please be careful to run the `npm install <package>` with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.

And npm official documentation about [legacy-peer-deps](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

> Use of `legacy-peer-deps` is not recommended, as it will not enforce the `peerDependencies` contract that meta-dependencies may rely on.